# Get wave file from azure blob storage memory stream

Tags: angularjs, azure-blob-storage, wav

I want to download a wav file from a blob storage container.I have the url to stream it on my angular app but I need to resample it.From the blob storage I get the byte array which looks like this:

"Bytes":"UklGRqS3AQBXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEAoA8AAEAfAAACABAAZGF0YYC3AQDg92H4xPzwAHf+RP9HAB4ATwFjAZgBoAEtASMBMQGGAR........"

I tried to create a blob file from that but I get an empty .wav file

var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: "audio/x-wav" });

saveAs(blob, "file.wav");

How can I get the .wav file format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#RIFF) so that i can resample it and download it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `FileSaver.js`. Here is my full sample code which downloads an image file from the Azure blob storage with `Angularjs 1.x` and `FileSaver.js`. And it worked well, you can take it as reference.

***index.html***

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="project">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/Blob.js/0cef2746414269b16834878a8abc52eb9d53e6bd/Blob.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/e9d941381475b5df8b7d7691013401e171014e89/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('project', [])

        .controller('ProjectController', function($http) {
            var project = this;
            project.yourName = "There";

            project.download = function() {
                var blobURL = "https://<my-storage-accout>.blob.core.windows.net/myimages/image.jpg";
                $http.get("blobURL", {
                    responseType: "arraybuffer"
                }).
                then(function(res) {
                    console.log("Read blob with " + res.data.byteLength + " bytes in a variable of type '" + typeof(res.data) + "'");

                    var blob = new Blob([res.data], {
                        type: "image/jpeg"
                    });
                    var filename = 'image.jpg';
                    saveAs(blob, filename);

                }, function(data, status) {
                    console.log("Request failed with status: " + status);
                });
            }
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="ProjectController as pro">

        <h1>Hello {{pro.yourName}}!</h1>
        <button type="button" ng-click="pro.download()">download</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```